# In Episode 462, why didn't the people turn into White Zetsu after Hagoromo and Hamura sealed Kaguya?

Tags: naruto

In Episode 462, it's shown that after Hagoromo and Hamura sealed Kaguya, everyone trapped in the divine tree came into existence and didn't turn into White Zetsu, which contradicts the fact that Black Zetsu said that everyone would become White Zetsu after the infinite tsyukomi.